# Installing kdesu on NixOS

Tags: kde-plasma, nix, nixos

When setting advanced properties on a program/link to start as another user it is throwing the error:

```
Sorry - Plasma
KDEInit could not launch 'kdesu':
Could not open library 'libkdeinit5_kdesu'.
Cannot load library /run/current-system/sw/lib/libkdeinit5_kdesu: (/run/current-system/sw/lib/libkdeinit5_kdesu.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

[image]

I tried to install kdesu using:

```
[root@nixos:~]# nix-env -qaP kdesu
nixos.kdeFrameworks.kdesu  kdesu-5.36.0

[root@nixos:~]# nix-env -iA nixos.kdeFrameworks.kdesu
replacing old ‘kdesu-5.36.0’
installing ‘kdesu-5.36.0’
building path(s) ‘/nix/store/2bn27h5drw0800gk5z2rmwfx78gqbbdc-user-environment’
created 2209 symlinks in user environment

[root@nixos:~]# kdesu
bash: kdesu: command not found

[root@nixos:~]# which kdesu
which: no kdesu in (/root/bin:/run/wrappers/bin:/etc/per-user-pkgs/root/bin:/root/.nix-profile/bin:/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin:/run/current-system/sw/bin)
```

I also tried installing `nix-env -iA nixos.kde-cli-tools` but that does not work either.

Any suggestions on how to get kdesu installed on NixOS?

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, unlike many distros on NixOS installing a library directly doesn't work as intended; the application that needs the library won't be able to find it. Instead, the package must declare all it's dependencies.

Packages which have optional dependencies tend to have a way to add them via configuration. You may want to try something like this in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`

```
services.xserver.desktopManager.plasma5.extraPackages = with kdeFrameworks; 
    [ kdesu
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad to see that you filed an issue on Nixpkgs, because this is not a configuration issue but a packaging bug.

It looks like `kdesu` lives in some `libexec` dir that doesn't hasn't been added to your PATH. It belongs to the `kde-cli-tools` package. You can run it with

`$(nix-build '<nixpkgs>' -A kde-cli-tools --no-out-link)/lib/libexec/kf5/kdesu`

You can use the above as an alias to launch `kdesu` until the [fix to the packaging bug](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/28426) arrives.